# How can I see/scrape the real text value hidden in page source?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, webbrowser-control, render

How can I scrape the real text value "2015-10-31" on the page while I can't see the real value in source page? I can scrape the right side of html, but I need to know the value "2015-10-31" shown in the left side. All I've searched is using selenium to auto render javascript, yet the result is meaningless to me because I want the real value in the table, instead the same result shown in Webkit. Any way to scrape this kind of hidden value?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value isn't shown in the page source because it is the value of the input in question.  Use get_attribute("value"):

```
browser.find_element_by_id("Estimated_Due_Date").get_attribute("value")
```